# How to fix amp-auto-ads on WordPress with with Error "Cannot resize element and overflow is not available"

Tags: html, css, amp-html

I am using Google AdSense Auto-Ads for AMP an a WordPress Website.
I placed the required snippet in the -Tag as well as the -Tag of the AMPHTML-page. Just as required by Google. And it worked quite well. Until a couple of days ago. AMP Auto-Ads stopped showing on AMP-Pages.

In the console I am getting the following error:

- No anchor element found
- Cannot resize element and overflow is not available

The amp-ad is showing with height="0" with seems odd to me. As shown in the screenshot and code below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLGmN.jpg

That's the link to my website and one of the not working AMP-pages:

https://www.randombrick.de/vpn-und-tor-zusammen-nutzen/amp/

- I validated the website via https://validator.ampproject.org and now issues so far.
- I switch the AMP WordPress Plugin from AMP to AMP for WordPress
- I tried to inject the code using the functions.php but switched back to AMP for WordPress Plugin.
- I cleared the cache using W3 Total Cache
- I deactivated each WordPress Plugin step by step, cleared the cache but couldn't find any plugin blocking the ads

I am actually lost and don't know what causes the AMP-Auto-Ads to collapse. Especially since it worked for weeks.

Does anyone have any idea why theses ads won't show? Apparently the amp-auto-ad code is within the AMP-page. But the ads won't appear.